# Why does this HTML looks different in an eBay listing than by itself?

Tags: html

[This](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8200042/Untitled-1.html) is the code by itself. [This](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8200042/normal.jpg) is how it looks by it self and how I want it to look. And [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8200042/ebay.jpg) is how I don't want it to look but how it looks when I copy and paste the whole HTML to my eBay listing. I get the same results on Chrome and IE. I'm not sure if is OK to copy and paste the whole HTML to the eBay listing, but I also tried pasting only the table and the CSS script but I got exactly the same results. I'm kinda new at HTML so I might be missing some obvious stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css is probably not compatible with ebay's. You can use tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to check the details and to find out which settings you will need to tweak. From the screenshots, I'm guessing you will need to set some padding to 0 explicitly.